# asp.net ошибка Не удалось найти данный ресурс. при возврате на главную страницу

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, веб-программирование

Запрошенный URL: /Nav/List
Хотя никакого файла лист по данному пути нет

Подскажите в чем ошибка, вот код

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@{
bool horizontal = ((bool)(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["horizontalNav"] ?? false));
string wrapperClasses = horizontal ? "btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-justified" : null;
}
<div class="@wrapperClasses">
@Html.ActionLink("Домой", "List", "Books",
new
{
    @class = horizontal ? "btn btn-default btn-sm" :
        "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"
})

@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(link, new
  {
   controller = "Books",
   action = "List",
   category = link,
   page = 1
 }, new
{
   @class = (horizontal ? "btn btn-default btn-sm"
            : "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg")
            + (link == ViewBag.SelectedNameGenre ? " btn-primary" : "")
})
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

у вас неправильно сформирована ссылка "Домой", семантика должна быть следующей:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Наименование ссылки", "ActionName", "ControllerName", 
new { 'атрибуты ссылки, такие как class и тд.' });
```

где:

- `ActionName` - это название действия выполнения, в вашем случае скорее всего будет *Index*
- `ControllerName` - название контроллера, может быть любым как и действие, но по умолчанию для главной страницы используется *Home*

Comment: я так понимаю Вы имеете ввиду что ТС использует тернарный оператор внутри блока формирования ссылки?!

Comment: @Bald56rus, нет, я имею ввиду что контроллер и действие заполнено не верными данными

Comment: <Зануда> а может у него метод называется `List` а контроллер `Books`</Зануда> меня вот больше смущает конструкция `@class = horizontal ? "btn btn-default btn-sm" : "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"`

Comment: @Bald56rus, пусть не смущает, это нормально. По всему остальному рекомендую прочитать первую строчку вопроса

Comment: все догнал, в приведенном коде у тс. ссылка домой формируется корректно, проблема где то в другом куске кода

Comment: @Bald56rus потому и расписано, что и для чего применяется